# Comment traduire « downgrade » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Dans le contexte informatique, il est souvent question d'*upgrade* et de *downgrade* de logiciel.

Autant pour *upgrade*, les traductions me viennent facilement : « mise à jour », « mise à niveau », autant pour l'opération inverse, le *downgrade* j'ai plus de difficultés à trouver une traduction aussi efficace.

Comment: Il me semble d'ailleurs que "mise à jour" traduira plutôt "update" alors que "mise à niveau" traduira plutôt "upgrade".

Comment: Computer programs are said only to be upgraded. Downgrade is not used for computers. It's for ranks or positions. ***The storm was downgraded*** from a category 5 to a category 4 weather event.

Comment: **There is a basic misunderstanding here: downgrade/upgrade a category, rank, rating or range, for example**. They are not antonyms in computing.

Comment: @Lambie [**What makes you feel they are not?**](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-upgrade-or-downgrade-select-db2-instances-between-various-product-offerings) By the way, this question was asked and answered 9 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peut-être pas en un seul mot, mais « ***Retour à une version antérieure*** » me semble être la bonne définition.

Comment: De façon amusante, cela pourrait aussi se dire "revert to previous version" qui est également assez difficile à traduire en français...

Comment: No one says "downgrade a program". retour à une version antérieure. Things that are downgraded are: categories or ranks, for example. Not applications or programs.

Answer (score 4):

Personnellement, je pense à la traduction suivante : *Rétrograder de version* ou *Revenir à une version antérieure*.

En *aparte*, dans le domaine informatique, on parle également souvent de *Rollback*.

Comment: J'ai pas mieux, mais si _revenir_ convient pour _rollback_, mais pour _downgrade_ a l'inconvénient d'impliquer qu'il s'agit d'un retour à une situation qui a existé, tandis que _downgrade_ peut s'employer quand on n'a jamais utilisé la version précédente.

Comment: @Un francophone : Tout à fait, j'ai eu la même réflexion. Cependant, je vois mal un utilisateur d'ores-et-déjà utiliser une version antérieure d'un logiciel sans avoir même essayer d'utiliser la dernière.

Answer (score 4):

Sur ce genre de question, je fais la différence entre le jargon technique et l'anglicisme.

La question m’a été posée pour la première fois en 1996. Depuis je n’ai jamais entendu ces mots autre part que dans la bouche de professionnels qui lisent les manuels techniques en VO de préférence à leur traduction.

Je continue, ainsi que les collègues que je côtoie, à utiliser *upgrade* et *downgrade* car ils sont compris immédiatement et sans ambiguïté.

Le jour où ces mots prendront un usage grand public (comme pour *télécharger*), je serai le premier à adopter leur nouvelle forme pour la vie de tous les jours, mais je continuerai probablement à *upgrader* et à « procéder à des *downgrades* contre les *bugs* de régressions » aussi longtemps que je *downloaderai*.

Comment: c'est également de cette manière que je procède. Mais je me demandais malgré tout si une traduction efficace existait

Comment: Poue être très franc, j'habite en Suisse. Donc si downgrade n'est pas compris,j'essaye zurückstufen puis, en deuxième recours, degradare. Qu'entendez-vous par traduction "efficace"?

Comment: "efficace"=se comprends sans explication supplémentaire ;) . Comme pour "upgrade" <=> "mise à jour", tout le monde comprends, c'est une traduction efficace ;).

Comment: En l'occurence, *downgrader* se comprend immédiatement. Pourquoi franciser? Ex: je me suis retapé le sql à la main pendant qu'il downgradait depuis un vieux backup.

Comment: Who says downgrade for returning to an earlier version of  a program due to bugs?  We say revert or go back to an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

The Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique [suggère](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8363698) *mise à niveau inférieur*.

Comment: Je suis professionel du domaine (français, pas québecois), et je ne suis pas sûr que je comprendrais ce terme sans contexte.

Comment: The GDT is right to a certain extent: The athletes' rankings were downgraded. But not a computer program or software. The rating for computer software can be downgraded.

Answer (score 1):

La traduction (déjà citée par ailleurs) la plus proche au niveau du sens serait pour moi :

> **Rétrograder**

cependant le terme me semble un peu trop connoté "conduite automobile" (descendre d'une vitesse).

Un terme équivalent qui me semble assez compréhensible serait :

> **Descente de version** ou **descente en version**

...Qui n'est sans doute pas ou peu utilisée, alors qu'en revanche, j'entends régulièrement :

> **Montée de version** ou **montée en version**